# while running console from SBT getting error "Couldn't retrieve source module: org.scala-sbt:compiler-interface:0.13.13:component"

Tags: scala, sbt

on Window command i install Scala and SBT .
while running console command from SBT getting below error  .

can some one help me to resolve this issue ?

getting below error 
**>sbt**

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to sujitd (in build file:/C:/Users/sujitd/)
```

**> console**

```
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\sujitd\target\scala-2.10\classes...
    [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.13 ...
    [warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/compiler-interface-0.13.13-sources.jar
    [info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
    [warn] Host repo.typesafe.com not found. url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
    [info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
    [warn] Host repo.scala-sbt.org not found. url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
    [info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
    [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar(src):  (0ms)
    [warn] ==== local: tried
    [warn]   C:\Users\sujitd\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\compiler-interface\0.13.13\srcs\compiler-interface-sources.jar
    [warn] ==== public: tried
    [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/compiler-interface-0.13.13-sources.jar
    [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
    [warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
    [warn] ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried
    [warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    [warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
    [warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    [warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar(src)
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compileIncremental for the full output.
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) sbt.InvalidComponent: Couldn't retrieve source module: org.scala-sbt:compiler-interface:0.13.13:component
    [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Apr 7, 2017 9:59:20 AM
```

Comment: can you place your build.sbt file here?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and while I am not sure what was causing it, here's a workaround that solved it for me:

Download `compiler-interface.jar` from [maven](https://maven.atlassian.com/maven-external/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/srcs/) for your version of sbt and put it in the local ivy cache.

Check sbt output to see local cache path for your system:

`[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\sujitd\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\compiler-interface\0.13.13\srcs\compiler-interface-sources.jar`

So, in this case you should put `compiler-interface-sources.jar` in  `C:\Users\sujitd\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\compiler-interface\0.13.13\srcs\`

Comment: Opened a bug report with the sbt project for this: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4478